# Some classes called +_closure$_x shows up in my ASP.NET MVC projects - what are they?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When adding a new strongly typed view in ASP.NET MVC, these weird classes show up:

[image]

What are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are compiler-generated classes that handle [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).  They're not unique to ASP.NET MVC.

This class will cause the compiler to generate one of these classes:

```
public class Foo
{
  private bool _bar = true;

  public Func<bool> HelloClosure()
  {
    return () => _bar;
  }
}
```

When someone outside of Foo calls HelloClosure, they get back a function that has a link back to that particular Foo instance.  Imagine we don't execute that function immediately and the GC comes along and collects Foo.  Now what happens when we execute the function?

```
var fooInstance = new Foo();
var func = fooInstance.HelloClosure();
fooInstance = null;
GC.Collect();
// assuming fooInstance is collected
var result = func.Invoke();
```

These automatically-generated classes manage these dependencies between functions and instances so that we don't get into a situation like this.